# How can I turn off subtitles in Totem?

Tags: video-player, totem

In "videos" (e.g. totem player), under Ubuntu 15.04, how do you turn off subtitles on a video that has them in metadata? All subtitle options in the Preferences are unticked. Setting their font size to 1 is not a great solution.

How do you prevent the video from immediately repeating when it finishes? The *Repeat* option on the Edit menu is unticked.

Comment: you cannot turn off subtitles if they are built-in.

Comment: @JoKeR: what about the repeat that repeats even if you tell it not to? Is that built in too?

Comment: nope I guess not :D but it sounds a common issue, you're not the first to ask this about repeat option, it might be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Setting them to size 1 is not a great solution, but setting them to size zero works!

You have to do it via `gsettings` though, the GUI will not allow size zero. Use the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.totem subtitle-font '[whatever your font is here], 0'
```

You can turn them off for the current video in the menu, but every time you start a new video they come back. As far as I can tell, this is the only way to set no subtitles as a default.